# Pad a number with a zero

Tags: printf, typeset

I'm trying to pad zero to a number

```
a=010
printf "%04d" $a
0008
```

I need the "output" as "0010"
it's converting the value.

and even tried with typeset

```
a=010
typeset -RZ2 a
echo $a
```

when I use the same in my script I got the following error:

```
Invalid -R option
```

Comment: the problem in with the input, not the output.

Answer (score 18):

Don't put a "0" at the beginning of the number -- it treats the number in the **octal** base. Simply assign the decimal number.

```
a=10    
printf "%04d" $a    
0010
```

If you are reading the numbers from somewhere else, you may consider removing the 0s at the beginning as follows:

```
a=0010    
b=$(echo $a | sed 's/^0*//')    
printf "%04d" $a    
0008
printf "%04d" $b    
0010
```

Comment: b=$(echo $a | sed 's/^0*//')

Comment: echo simply prints the value of the variable a, which is then redirected to sed (using the | character). Now, sed receives the string (i.e., value of a), and removes all the 0s at the beginning. The character ^ indicates beginning of a line; 0* means any number of zeroes including none. This essentially returns you the number with all 0s, if any, at the beginning removed. This value is then assigned to a new variable called b.

Comment: Please, whipe useless pipe!  Write `b=$(sed s/^0*// <<<"$a")`

Answer (score 15):

## New answer using `%08.0f`

As `%f` is used to print *decimal floating point*, argument **must be** decimal.

So there is no risk to see argument interpreted as *octal*:

Do simply:

```
a=0010

a=`printf %08.0f $a`
```

or

```
a=$(printf %08.0f $a)
```

then

```
echo $a
00000010
```

This work find under any **POSIX [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)**

#### Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could avoid fork by using `-v` option of `printf`:

```
a=0010
printf -v a %08.0f $a
echo $a
00000010
```

## Old answer (using `%d`)

#### Under POSIX [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)

You can drop the left `0` character with the following:

```
a=00010
while [ "$a" != "${a#0}" ] ;do a=${a#0};done
printf "%08d" $a
00000010
```

As this doesn't fork a new command session, this could be quicker than using `sed`.

#### Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

You can force decimal interpretation with the following syntax:

```
a=000010
printf "%08d" $((10#$a))
00000010
```

This could be useful for conversions:

```
a="0a"
printf "%04d" $((16#$a))
0010

a="00001010"
printf "%04d" $((2#$a))
0010

a="00012"
printf "%04d" $((8#$a))
0010

a="0020"
printf "%04d" $((5#$a))
0010

a="0013"
printf "%04d" $((7#$a))
0010
```

and so on...

```
a="zz"
printf "%04d" $((36#$a))
1295
```

Comment: b=$(echo $a | sed 's/^0*//') what exactly this step does ??

Comment: @user43067 `$()` generate a new command session (*fork*), `echo $a` will run in this new session, than `| sed` will generate a new command session to *pipe* to `/bin/sed` outer binary.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish that by using a different conversion specifier, for example the "f" specifier. From the [printf manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> f, F
>
> The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation in
>   the style [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after the
>   decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If
>   the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is
>   explicitly zero, no decimal-point character appears. If a decimal
>   point appears, at least one digit appears before it.

But we don't really want a floating point representation of your number, so we must specify a precision of zero. This should do it:

```
a=010
printf "%04.0f" $a
```

I'm assuming you are using Linux, but this should also work with other flavours of Unix.

Comment: Or, from `man printf`, u could use: `printf "%04g" 010`! +1, interesting way to explore too...

Answer (score 4):

`typeset -Z4 a` will work with `zsh` or `ksh`.

When interpreted as a number, In POSIX sh and printf, if there's a leading zero, it's interpreted as an octal number. So, you need to strip those `0`s first:

```
printf '%04d\n' "${a#"${a%%[!0]*}"}"
```

Or you could use `awk` that doesn't have that issue:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "%04d\n", ARGV[1]}' "$a"
```